# How to bypass username password dialogs in TortoiseHg?

Tags: tortoisehg

I checked online and they are suggesting to save your username pass in user global settings file, which I checked and Tortoise already saved them as plain text. But it's still asking me the same username and pass 50 different times when I want to update to a specific changelist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Save your username and password in `mercurial.ini`:

   ```
   [auth]
   xxx.prefix = https://bitbucket.org/
   xxx.username = USERNAME
   xxx.password = PASSWORD
   ```
2. Use SSH keys instead and follow setup steps in this post: [Set up SSH for Mercurial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Mercurial). This way doesn't need to store your password in plain text.

Comment: Thanks, where do I have to put this INI file? Because I already have those fields when I edit user settings file from the GUI?

Comment: @JoanVenge For the first method, `mercurial.ini` will be under path `"C:\Users\your-user-name\mercurial.ini"`. And make sure `Pageant.exe` running in background with your SSH key loaded.

Comment: @JoanVenge To be clear, `Pageant.exe` running in background with SSH loaded is only needed for the second method.